# Workflow Foundation: How to get the WorkflowInstance being inside of a SequenceActivity?

Tags: workflow-foundation

How can I get the WorkflowInstance executing a SequenceActivity (being inside of the Activity)?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to get a WorkflowInstanceProxy using a custom IWorkflowInstanceExtension. You will need to create the extension to capture the instance and then create a custom activity to pull the instance proxy from the extension.

Something like http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/02/26/getting-your-workflow-instance.aspx